# Cordova app won't log in via facebook

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, logcat, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that works great in the browser. However, I built the app for android, and on the device I cannot even login. When I tap the "Login with facebook" button, I get this output from Logcat:

```
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
D/CordovaLog( 2241): file:///android_asset/www/js/loginCtrl.js: Line 51 : Login
I/chromium( 2241): [INFO:CONSOLE(51)] "Login", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/loginCtrl.js (51)
D/ConnectPlugin( 2241): login FB
E/PluginManager( 2241): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager( 2241): com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_actions) to a request for read authorization
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at com.facebook.Session.validatePermissions(Session.java:1291)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:1194)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:471)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.execute(ConnectPlugin.java:247)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:84)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:147)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/PluginManager( 2241):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D/CordovaLog( 2241): file:///android_asset/www/js/loginCtrl.js: Line 75 : Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_actions) to a request for read authorization
I/chromium( 2241): [INFO:CONSOLE(75)] "Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_actions) to a request for read authorization", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/loginCtrl.js (75)
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
D/dalvikvm( 2241): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3376K, 51% free 3462K/6940K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
D/dalvikvm( 2241): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 51% free 3462K/6940K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 13ms
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 2241): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

My theory is that on my facebook dashboard, I have only created the app as a website with site url `http://localhost:8100/`

I believe I'd need to set it up as an android app, but I do not have a package name, main activity class, or key hashes because it is a javascript ionic app rather than a traditional android app.

Comment: It seems like you are having troubles with permissions to me. Check into that maybe.

Comment: As I mentioned, my theory is that I haven't authorized Android on my facebook dashboard. Do you know how to find the package name and key hashes of an ionic app?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to retrieve those.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling in Facebook authentication once a few months ago. I have a vague memory that configuration for Facebook button is quite a big big big problem in Phonegap apps.

How about trying Facebook OAuth as another solution instead of "Facebook button"?

[Useful article for Facebook OAuth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth)

OAuth is also useful when you also need authentication for twitter, google ?